# Simple React+Redux app causes "WARNING: The final argument passed to useMemo changed size between renders." for every state change

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux

I have made a very simple react+redux app, but with any action dispatched, I get 7 warnings in browser console regarding mismatch in arguments of `useMemo`. Below is the first one:

```
Warning: The final argument passed to useMemo changed size between renders. The order and size of this array must remain constant.

Previous: [[object Object]]
Incoming: [[object Object], function () {
        // Distinguish between actual "data" props that were passed to the wrapper component,
        // and values needed to control behavior (forwarded refs, alternate context instances).
        // To maintain the wrapperProps object reference, memoize this destructuring.
        var forwardedRef = props.forwardedRef,
            wrapperProps = Object(_babel_runtime_helpers_esm_objectWithoutPropertiesLoose__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__["default"])(props, ["forwardedRef"]);

        return [props.context, forwardedRef, wrapperProps];
      }, 0]
    in ConnectFunction
    in Provider
```

I am not using `useMemo` myself and it is only being triggered from `react-redux` package and simplified the code so much to get to this and still I cannot figure out what to do to identify the issue. Any ideas? (below is my entire code)

```typescript
import * as React from 'react';
import * as ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { connect, Provider } from "react-redux";
import { createStore, Dispatch } from 'redux';

const increment = () => ({ type: 'INCREMENT' });
const counterReducer =
    (state = 10, action: { type: string }) => (action.type === 'INCREMENT') ? state + 1 : state;

interface Props { count: number }
interface Actions { inc: () => {} };
class AppComponent extends React.Component<Props & Actions> {
    render = () =>
    (<>
        Count: {this.props.count}
        <button onClick={this.props.inc}>+</button>
    </>);
}
const mapStateToProps = (state: number) : Props => ({ count: state });
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch: Dispatch) => ({ inc: () => dispatch(increment()) });
const App = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(AppComponent);

ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={createStore(counterReducer)}>
        <App />
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById("root")
);
```

**Edit**: Here are the dependencies from `package.json`:

```json
{
  ....
  "dependencies": {
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.2.1",
    "react": "^16.9.11",
    "react-dom": "^16.9.4",
    "react-hot-loader": "^4.12.18",
    "react-redux": "^7.1.3",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^16.9.11",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.9.4",
    "@types/react-redux": "^7.1.3",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "^5.2.1",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^5.1.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "prettier": "^1.19.1",
    "typescript": "^3.7.4",
    "webpack": "^4.41.5",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.10",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.10.1"
  }
  ....
}
```

There are actually more warnings and they all come from the `connect` part of `react-redux`. Every call of `useMemo` in the [`ConnectFuncion`](https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/blob/9ebd1a931b05f05380c44336dd369fc084474edf/src/components/connectAdvanced.js#L149) is causing a warning similar to that.

Comment: it's worked for me without any warning!

Comment: @Alex Here is the full code: https://github.com/Reza1024/react-typescript-webpack-rush-template/tree/warning
you probably need to do a `rush update` and `rush build` first before doing `npm run start` in the `app` folder

Comment: @RezaJooyandeh the repo doesn't have package.json, can you add to the repo.

Comment: Which versions are you using when you tested and did not see any warnings?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found the issue. It was caused by I had configured `react-hot-loader`. Looking to my `webpack.config.js`

```typescript
module.exports = {
    entry: [
        './src/boot.tsx',
        'react-hot-loader/patch'
    ],
    ...
};
```

and reading the [description](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-hot-loader) of `react-hot-reload` package:

> prepend your webpack entry point

So the issue was only the order of the items in the entry point of the package, swapping them resolved the issue:

```typescript
module.exports = {
    entry: [
        'react-hot-loader/patch',
        './src/boot.tsx'    
    ],
    ...
};
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks similar to https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/issues/3421 and is due to a mismatching version of React and Redux. `react-redux > 7.x` needs `react > 16.8.3`

Comment: Thank you for your help. It might be related to that, but in my case I am using `react >= 16.9.17` so looking at `pnpm-lock.yaml` the version of `react` that is selected is `16.12.0`